# How to access the HashMap values in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, hashmap

I have an activity in which I am having an `edittext` in which i am entering something and storing that value in `HashMap` where the data inserted in `edittext` is the key and static data is the value. Now I am  passing that to DialogFragment but I am not able to access the key in DialogFragment. How to access the key in DialogFragment to access the value  associated with that key

Here is the code:

## MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="grepthorsoft.com.hash.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/tt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bt"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

## MainActivity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    HashMap<String, String> d;
    EditText et;
    String s;
    FragmentManager fm;
    Button bt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        d = new HashMap<>();
        et = findViewById(R.id.tt);
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        bt = findViewById(R.id.bt);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                s = et.getText().toString();
                d.put(s, "2");

                MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(d);
                myDialog.show(fm, "test");

            }
        });    
    }
}
```

## MyDialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout


    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="grepthorsoft.com.hash.MyDialog">

</RelativeLayout>
```

## MyDialog.java

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment{

    Button yes,no;    
    HashMap<String,String> d;

  public  MyDialog(){}

    public MyDialog( HashMap<String,String> d)
    {
        this.d=d;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);   
    }    
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my_dialog,null);

      return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

  }
}
```

Comment: please feel free to update if you got your solution..

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the value in your onclick function using `setArguments` like this..

```
         MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(d);
         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         bundle.putSerializable("hashmap",mMap);
         myDialog.setArguments(bundle);
         myDialog.show(fm, "test");
```

And then you will get those value using `getArguments` in yoyr `MyDialog` fragment
paste this code in your `onCreateView`

```
      Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            if(bundle.getSerializable("hashmap") != null)
                mMap = (HashMap<String, String>)bundle.getSerializable("hashmap"); 

//get your hashmap value
    Iterator iterator = mMap.keySet().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key=(String)iterator.next();
            String value=(String)mMap.get(key);
        }
```

`hasNext()` Returns true if the iteration has more elements.

`next()` Returns the next element in the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your **dialog fragment** ...

```
for ( String key : d.keySet() ) { 


    System.out.println("value" + d.get(key )); 

 }
```

> `d.keySet()` fetches all the keys from the hashmap `d`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in wrong way.. you should pass any data to DialogFragment via DialogFragment.setArguments() method. For example:

in MainActivity class ->

```
 MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();

            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putSerializable("HashMap",d);
            myDialog.setArguments(extras);
            myDialog.show(fm, "test");
```

in myDialog class keep only default constructor and remove your constructor and then add this code to onActivityCreated method

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

    if(bundle != null) {
        d = (HashMap<String, String>) bundle.getSerializable("HashMap");
    }
```

for more information you can check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can access hashmap declare in activity class into the dialog by making hashmap public in the activity and in dialog fragment class access object like this ((MainActivity)getActivity()).d;

and in dialog fragment, you can iterate map like this

```
void printMap() {
    Iterator it = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).d.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());

    }
}
```